# which is most preferrable data structure to get output into, arrays or object ? and why?

Tags: php, wordpress

Does output format have any effect on the overall performance of a script? For example we sometimes get the option to select an output format (either array or object), in a php based cms.

The only difference I know between the two is:

If we select array, we use

```
$example['key1'] = $dummydata;
```

but if output format is "object", we use

```
$example->key1 = $dummydata;
```

Is this the only reason (just the accessibility) why we should one of the options over the other?  Or there are other things to take into account too?  Which format is better between these?
Example 
this is a code snippet from wordpress where we get option to choose output type

```
$wpdb->get_row('query', output_type, row_offset);

$sql = "select * from ".$wpdb->prefix."sampletable where user_id =".$user->ID;
$result_set = $wpdb->get_row($sql, ARRAY_A);
```

Comment: Do show an example of where this option can be found, otherwise we can only answer vaguely.

Comment: okey ..let me edit it

Comment: i have edited .. its wordpress

Answer (score 2):

If you use only stdClass objects, there's hardly any difference. In that case, I'd even go for arrays since they are more flexible to work with (e.g. key names are more flexible) and you have a ton of functions to work with (array merging, diffing etc.).

The *best* option is to go full OO and define your data structures as classes. This gives you type safety, type hintability, object methods etc. Again, just "typeless" stdClass objects give you none of that and don't even provide the feature-richness of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I searched [`wordpress output_type`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/106235) and [this page in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Examples).

The generic object vs array argument I gave before in this answer is not that relevant here, I feel. Do consider what you wish to do with the data afterwards. If you are going to write your own functions to handle the data, then an array is as good as an object.

If you have operations that make use of the existing logic in some objects, for example [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), then by all means use the `OBJECT` return type.

Comment: i dont want definition and usage of each of those. thankyou though

Comment: Yep, I know, I was working on a proper answer then I had to leave for lunch :P The point is that objects allow for different methods of access as well, but arrays are just data storage.

However, I see that none of us seems to have answered your question. This was the generic 'array vs object' answer I'd hoped you would have avoided.

Answer (score -2):

Array
 not reuse friendly, often u built once, use it once
 not data protection friendly
 not default reference friendly
 public friendly
Object
reuse friendly, you could use it some other place in project
data protection friendly
default reference friendly

Comment: I can't much make sense out of this answer.